# How to specify number multidimension in kernel call in openCL

Tags: c++, syntax, opencl

In cuda we can do stuff like:

```
my_kernel<<< n_x,n_y >>>(...)
```

what's the equivalent in opencl?

Answer (score 1):

This is done by specifying the "Global Work Size" parameter.

```
size_t work_sizes[] = {1024, 1024, 64};
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 3, nullptr, work_sizes, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
```

If you prefer the C++ idiom:

```
std::vector<size_t> work_sizes = {1024, 1024, 64};
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, work_sizes.size(), nullptr, work_sizes.data(), nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Most OpenCL implementations only support up to 3 dimensions of work items, but if your implementation supports more, then you can specify as many as is allowed. And obviously, if you are only working with a single-dimension of work items, that's easy to specify too:

```
std::vector<size_t> work_sizes = {16777216};
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, work_sizes.size(), nullptr, work_sizes.data(), nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Comment: Just discovered that, I'd also point out this https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html